# Angular cast formgroup to object with less parameters

Tags: angular, forms, casting

i made a form in angular. The form is working perfectly. Now i need to cast the form to a newCustomer object. The form has a checkbox but the newCustomer doesn't.My code now doesn't have errors but the console.log(user)does nothing.
All help is appriciated.
My component code:

```
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  bool:boolean = false;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2),Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      firstName:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2),Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      email:['', [Validators.required,Validators.email]],
      telephone:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[0-9]{9}")]],
      mobilePhone:['',[Validators.pattern("[0-9]{10}")]],
      type:['',Validators.required],
      checkbox:[],
      companyName:['',[Validators.minLength(2),Validators.maxLength(30)]],
      rizivNumber:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]{8}")],
      taxNumber:['',Validators.pattern("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]*")],
      streetName:['', Validators.required],
      houseNumber:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[0-9]{1,5}")]],
      bus:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]*")],
      zipCode:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("[0-9]{4}")]],
      place:['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(2),Validators.maxLength(30)]],
      fstreetName:[''],
      fhouseNumber:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]*")],
      fbus:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]*")],
      fzipCode:['',Validators.pattern("[0-9]{4}")],
      fplace:[''],
      privacy:['',[Validators.requiredTrue]]
    })
    this.formControlValueChanged();
   }

  public onFormSubmit() {
    if(this.registerForm.valid) {
      let user = new NewCustomer();
        user = this.registerForm.value;
        console.log(user)
        /* Any API call logic via services goes here */
    }
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  formControlValueChanged() {
    this.registerForm.get('checkbox').valueChanges.subscribe(
        (mode: string) => {
            this.updateForm();
        });
}

getClass(text:string){
  var input = this.registerForm.get(text);
  if(input.invalid && input.touched){
    return "input-group has-error"
  }else{
    return "input-group";
  }
}

}
```

This is my html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Account informatie</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('name')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="Achternaam*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('firstName')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="Voornaam*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('email')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email*">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('telephone')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="telephone" placeholder="Telefoon*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('mobilePhone')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" formControlName="mobilePhone" placeholder="GSM">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('type')">
                        <label for="sel1">Type klant:</label>
                        <select value="type klant" class="form-control" formControlName="type" >
                            <option>Particulier</option>
                            <option>Zorgprofessional met RIZIV-nummer</option>
                            <option>Zorgvoorziening</option>
                            <option>Andere professional</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Bedrijfsgegevens</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('companyName')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('rizivNumber')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control"formControlName="rizivNumber" placeholder="RIZIV-nummer">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('taxNumber')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="taxNumber" placeholder="BTW-nummer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h3>Afleveradres</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('streetName')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetName" placeholder="Straatnaam*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('houseNumber')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-5-1"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="houseNumber" placeholder="Huisnummer*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('bus')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="bus" placeholder="Bus">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('zipCode')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="zipCode" placeholder="Postcode*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('place')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="place" placeholder="Plaats*">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="bool">
            <h3>Facturatie adres</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('fstreetName')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fstreetName" placeholder="Straatnaam*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('fhouseNumber')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sound-5-1"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="fhouseNumber" placeholder="Huisnummer*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('fbus')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fbus" placeholder="Bus">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('fzipCode')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="fzipCode" placeholder="Postcode*">
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('fplace')">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="fplace" placeholder="Plaats*">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox"  name="">Facturatie adres is verschillend van afleveradres<br>
                    </div>
                    <div [ngClass]="getClass('privacy')">
                        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="privacy"  name="">Ik accepteer de <a href="https://www.caredeal.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/HL_Algemene-Verkoopsvoorwaarden_010818.pdf">algemene voorwaarden</a> en heb de <a href="https://www.caredeal.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Privacy-Notification_NL_250718.pdf">privacy disclaimer</a> gelezen.<br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button type="submit" [disabled] = "!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The class i want the form to be casted too:

```
export class NewCustomer {
    //Account information
    name:string;
    firstName:String;
    email:String;
    phonenumber:string;
    mobilePhone:string;
    typeCustomer:Type;
    customTypeCustomer:string;

    //Company information

    companyName:String;
    rizivNumber:number;
    taxNumber:String;

    //Delivery adres
    streetName:string;
    houseNumber:string;
    bus:string;
    zipCode:string;
    place:string;

    //Facturation adres
    fStreetName:string;
    fHouseNumber:string;
    fBus:string;
    fZipCode:string;
    fPlace:string;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let user = new NewCustomer();
user = this.registerForm.value;
```

By doing that, you actually erase the `NewCustomer` object : assigning the value of the form to your variable changes the memory reference to a plain object : it's a typeless object containing the values of your form.

If you want to apply the form to your `NewCustomer` object, I suggest you do this :

```js
let user = new NewCustomer();

// Applies only existing keys in NewCustomer
Object.keys(this.registerForm.value)
  .forEach(key => key in NewCustomer? user[key] = this.registerForm.value[key] : null);

// Applies all keys, even the ones not existing in NewCustomer
Object.keys(this.registerForm.value)
  .forEach(key => user[key] = this.registerForm.value[key] : null)
```